# Git: applying "--all" stashed files to several branches?

Tags: git

```
// while in the dev-branch
git stash save --all "saving my modified files and everything else"
// create a new branch
git checkout -b problem-branch dev-branch  
// get stashed stuff to new branch
git stash apply

// commit and push to new branch
git add .
git commit -m "My problem-branch is done."
git push --set-upstream origin problem-branch

// go back to original branch
git checkout dev-branch
// take the stashed stuff
git stash apply
// check
git status
// no modified files were taken from stash. where are they?
```

I've stashed my changes, and switched from `dev-branch` to `problem-branch`. I applied the stashed stuff to `problem-branch`, fixed, commited.

I checked back out the `dev-branch`, applied the stashed stuff again - but there isn't any changed files that I saved to stash?

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Any* use of `git stash save --include-untracked` or `git stash save --all` is suspect, because such stashes are difficult to apply again later.  There's one situation where it works well, which is the initial `git stash apply` that you did: that's why the *first* one worked.  All the subsequent ones, however, will try to restore untracked files (with `--all`, this includes the ignored untracked files too) that already exist, which will fail *because* they already exist.

As [czupe notes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66049423/1256452), you *can* use `git checkout` (or, in Git 2.23 or later, `git restore`) to extract the content of the [`W` commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)—see [the discussion section on the linked `git stash` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#_discussion)—but this *is* the file-destroying variant of `git checkout`, which is why it's in the `git restore` subset and not the `git switch` subset in Git 2.23+.  If you're going to use `git stash` extensively,<sup>1</sup> it's probably wiser to get in the habit of using it without `--all` or `--include-untracked`.

If you do have an `--all` stash you want to apply again, *and* are *sure* it's OK to wipe out this other branch's untracked files including ignored ones, use `git clean -dfx`, after which you'll (probably) be able to `git stash apply` the same stash again.  Be aware that Git can't help you recover from a bad `git clean` operation, since you're removing files that are not in any normal Git commit (but because of the `--all`, *are* in this particular stash, in the `U` commit that is added to such a stash, but is not shown in the documentation.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Personally, I recommend against getting in the habit of using `git stash` at all, though it's received a bit of attention lately and is now less-bad than it used to be.  The ultimate problem, though, is that all `git stash` does is make some commits.  The two or sometimes three commits it makes don't play very well with other parts of Git.  If you need to make commits—which is all `git stash` will do—why not make *ordinary* commits, which *do* play well with the rest of Git?  The two things you'll need to learn are how to slice a commit off the end of a branch once you're done with it, and how to slice one out of the last few commits in case you accidentally add a commit "past" the one you didn't mean to put in.  These are both valuable skills in their own right, so it's not as though you would learn these *only* to avoid `git stash`.

Comment: I have no problem with `git clean -dfx` - after that `git stash apply` finally worked. The modified files are there. Didn't know `--all` was that tricky, will probably avoid it in the future unless I really need it.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason, maybe trivial that your `git stash apply` did not work.
Somehow stash was cleaned, dropped, or for other reasons.

If I would be in your shoes I would check my stash difference, would do some
investigations. List my stash:
`git stash list`
Check my last stash changed files:
`git stash show`
Check the content of the files of my last stash:
`git stash show -p`

Also, it is possible that there was some error message, I see many reasons behind that.

Comment: I got many "(file) already exists, no checkout" messages for untracked files, and final "error: could not restore untracked files from stash". However, the modified files were not mentioned. They are just not poped from stash. 
`git stash list` lists the stash at `stash@{0}`.

Comment: Ok, my best guess is that you have those files on your directory as well (recreated, or did not push it from last branch), but now those files are untracked. And you would like to override them with stash, so probably the error message looks like:   ```2file.txt already exists, no checkout
1file.txt already exists, no checkout
...
Could not restore untracked files from stash entry```

If you do not care what is it in those untracked files, then you can just ```git checkout stash -- .``` this will overwrite your untracked files, BUT YOU WILL LOOSE THE CONTENT OF THOSE.